# How do I configure Microsoft Teams' Stack Overflow Connector?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I was excited to read about [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-available/?cb=1)(SOTeams), but my company uses Microsoft Teams (MSTeams), and before we start trialing SOTeams, I was curious if we could set up the integration between the two -- it'd definitely help adoption if we could automatically post new SOTeams questions to our chat client!

MSTeams has a "Stack Overflow Connector" available on the MSTeams app store. When you configure it, it prompts you to enter in Stack Overflow account info. It looks like this:

[image]

I set up a configuration for questions tagged "C#" delivered individually, and this worked fine - the questions were posted by the bot as expected.

What was unexpected was that all of my team members were able to see the "Comment", "Upvote / Downvote", and "Post Answer" buttons despite the fact that only *my* personal Stack Overflow account had been registered with the connector.

That... doesn't seem intended. Is there some way to configure the MSTeams Stack Overflow Connector to either:

- Not allow Answers, comments, votes, etc. directly through the bot's postings?
- Force users to setup their own Stack Overflow account so that the above-mentioned actions are done on *their* account instead of *mine*?

Comment: Is the connector published by Stack Exchange? I thought I've read that currently there is no official MS Teams integration for SO Teams, but maybe I'm wrong. In the case I remembered this correctly, you might also want to try using the "Send feedback" link to contact the actual maintainers of the connector.

Comment: I'm not actually sure -- the bot lists itself as "Created by
Microsoft Teams Ecosystem", and the primary reference i can find to it is this one from [Microsoft themselves](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/Automate-your-workflows-using-Connectors-in-Microsoft-Teams/ba-p/113564)

Comment: I think this should be tagged [MicrosoftTeams-for-StackOverflow], not [StackOverflow-for-Teams] which is a completely different thing?

Comment: @Bergi By all means - I don't have the rep to create tags here.

Comment: @TuringTux considering that the connector was available since '17, I doubt it was specifically designed for SO4T

Comment: So... does the connector connect to Stack Overflow, or Stack Overflow for Teams? Reading the text it looks like it connects to the main site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After grabbing one of my coworkers, I can confirm that despite the optics, the "Add an answer" "Add a comment" etc. buttons will not work for them without registering their own Stack Overflow account.

[image]

So chalk this up to user error - your account is still safely yours, and the integration appears to work just fine! (Though it remains to be seen if this will work with team-specific Tags for SOTeams)