# How to use custom tags in Microsoft Teams' Stack Overflow Connector?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm trying to connect Stack Overflow for Teams to our Microsoft Teams instance. We have the connector setup, and it doesn't allow us to put our own tags in to run rules off of it. How are these tags populated?

We want to be able to tag an issue in Stack Overflow, and then have that connector look for that tag and post it in our teams.

Also, is there a reason why "Deliver individual messages as new posts arrive" is grayed out and doesn't work?

Comment: [How do I configure Microsoft Teams' Stack Overflow Connector?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367559/how-do-i-configure-microsoft-teams-stack-overflow-connector) is related, right?

Comment: @rene, related but they were trying to solve a different problem. Ours doesn't even post as individual messages arrive. Also, we're wanting to use a tag we use in our Stack Overflow For Teams account. And we can't do that.

Comment: [Are questions about third-party connectors to Teams on-topic on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375689/are-questions-about-third-party-connectors-to-teams-on-topic-on-meta?noredirect=1&lq=1)