# Are questions about third-party connectors to Teams on-topic on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, stack-overflow-for-teams

Today a new question was asked about the [Stack Overflow Connector of Microsoft Teams](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/Automate-your-workflows-using-Connectors-in-Microsoft-Teams/ba-p/113564) which seems to be a Microsoft product.

[How to use custom tags in Microsoft Teams' Stack Overflow Connector?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375688/how-to-use-custom-tags-in-microsoft-teams-stack-overflow-connector?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Back in May we had this one:

[How do I configure Microsoft Teams' Stack Overflow Connector?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367559/578411)

Both questions focus on the integration aspect of that Connector with Stack Overflow for Teams. Customers of SOfT are told that MSO is their support site.

Are questions that are about third party products but rely on the Stack Exchange API on-topic?

If yes, would introducing a tag for [stack-overflow-connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-connector) be in order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This takes some unpacking.

The product that is being used is "Microsoft Teams" ("Teams"). The product that it connects to is "Stack Overflow for Teams" ("SO"). Users of Teams are attempting to connect to SO through this connector.

It's not the case that this connector is officially supported, endorsed, or ordained by Stack Exchange itself as an official way to connect to SO, but people are doing it *anyway* and want to ask questions about it.

My takeaway: it's *probably* on-topic on Super User. (Take that with the largest chunk of salt you can heave into your office.) I view it as a question asking about software which isn't explicitly about programming said software; effectively, you're looking for a way to connect your [Trillian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillian_(software)) client to an IRC channel.

Comment: 30 pounds of salt.  NOW what do I do with it!?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is viable for a user that has just an account to access their Stack Overflow for Teams to expect to post on Super User for an issue that could well be a support case for the Stack Oveflow for Teams product they pay for. I get where you want to go with this but I'm more inclined to say these are examples that would go on a true SOfT meta, had it existed. Until that site comes into existence I think we're supposed to be minding the store?

Comment: I consider myself to be highly allergic to Microsoft Teams, since I don't use the product (and can't; they've explicitly stated that they're not going to support Linux desktop).  I also consider this matter to be one of an edge case.  It's very much the case that there may be some wonky SOfT connectivity issues between Teams and itself, but no one here in an official capacity is responsible for the connector.  I *really* do feel like it's a Trillian-like use case in which you have a general purpose chat tool used to wire into something else.

Comment: (Also, anything that we *don't* have to deal with on Meta is a good thing to not deal with.)

Comment: @rene Why would MSO be minding the store for some third-party product?

Comment: @PaulCrovella if it was just a third-party product, sure. My point is that the issues raised could be caused by a regression on the SE-API-interface which is shared with Stack Overflow for Teams. Keeping MSO at its bare minimum to support a paid SE product is what I'm looking for. Based on your comment I conclude you say: we don't need to support 3rd party integration products at all, those questions should be closed, right?

Comment: @rene An API problem would be between Microsoft and SO to hash out. Supporting Microsoft's end users directly on the off chance there's an API problem is quiet the leap, and would be missing critical information even if it was the case. Yes, I believe those questions are off topic here on MSO.

Comment: @fbueckert - Suck it and see :-)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that'd be for meta, as the Microsoft SO connector product is not affiliated with, endorsed by or maintained by Stack Exchange. As such, it's not "about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network". In theory it is about Stack Overflow, yes, but as far as I know we also don't really allow programming questions about the SO API.

It might be a better fit as a software configuration / server administration question on superuser, but I'm not a user there so that might not apply either.